# Open image as a layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I open an image in Photoshop as a layer in the current document?

Currently, I have to do it manually like this: open the image file, click on its layer and duplicate it to the other document (image). Is there a way to do this directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the *Place* function: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> while having the target document open.